# Angular. How can I get a value in object that is in array?

Tags: angular, typescript

If I need to get 59, how can I do it?

```
data = [
   {name: 'AK', price: 50, amount: 1, total: 50},

   {name: 'UMP', price: 59, amount: 1, total: **59**}
]
```

Comment: `data[1].total`?

Comment: I think some more clarification would help get a more suitable answer. Like others have said, are you searching for a specific value which is dynamically generated? are you always just looking for a value of 59? are you looking for that total b/c of the name on the object. I think you see what i mean, since there are several very simple ways to do this, however if you are handling dynamic data it makes things somewhat more complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data array is static:

```
 data[1].total
```

else

```
  const getObjectHavingTotal59 = this.data.filter(e=>{
          return e.total===59;
        })
```

then

```
getObjectHavingTotal59[0].total;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking solution with Array iteration

```
for (let dt of data) {
    console.log(dt.total);
}
```

if you are looking for a solution on condition-based then

```
data.find(dt => dt.name === 'UMP').total;
```